# Why does my array not get reassigned when I shuffle it?

Tags: javascript

**Update**
After further testing it does appear to work, however the console output is incorrect; both arrays still look exactly the same.

---

I am using the Fisher-Yates (Knuth) shuffle as described by this post (code near bottom): http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

This code correctly shuffles an array of elements. I have tested this in console to verify. I am working on a project where I need to shuffle an array of arrays. This code correctly shuffles the array of arrays, as it is data agnostic.

However, when I try to assign the array to the new value, it does not change. For example:

```
data = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9'],['10','11','12']];
data = shuffle(data); //Value of data does not change, even though shuffle works
```

When I do

```
shuffle(data);
```

in the console it returns a correctly shuffled array of arrays.

I have created this JSFiddle so you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/herbstmb/Ve24U/

If you look in your console clearly the shuffle works but the assignment fails.

Many thanks for any help understanding what's going on.

Comment: Works just fine here, using Chrome !

Comment: Since the reference to `data` never changes, the output will be identical both times you log the array. If you replace `console.log(data)` with `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`, you will see the different values.

Comment: @TylerEich Other than adding killing the nice formatting by making it a string and adding bunch of unneeded slashes that worked great, thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see, you thought it would return a different array, and not the same array. As it is, it just changes the array, and doing `array2 = array1` does not a new array make, it just gives you two variables referencing the same array. If you want to return a new array, just change it a little, here you go -> http://jsfiddle.net/Ve24U/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does. Array are mutable. You get the same log in the console because they are both the shuffled result. You logged the unshuffled array first, but you inspected it after shuffled, then it is has changed. Check at the array values in the console and in the source, they differ.

Comment: So the value that was logged prior to the shuffle is updated after the shuffle as well, and that is why I thought it wasn't working even though it is?

Comment: It doesn't change the values in console.  `log` just hasn't evaluated the array until after `shuffle` has been called.  if there was a delay after the first `console.log` but prior to the `shuffle` I'd expect to see different results.

Comment: @JuanGarcia is correct. In Javascript, variables are mutable and passed by reference. If you want to make it functional, you could copy the array within the Shuffle method and return the shuffled version. This would ensure that the variable data remains untouched.

Comment: @user2708395 You'd be correct in many cases however, the way Chrome handles logging is unique.  It will fully evaluate the object and dump it to the javascript console immutably.  consider `var mouse=new Array(3);mouse[0]='jake';var cat=[mouse];console.log(cat);mouse[1]='ted';console.log(cat);`  If you type slow enough there will be two different cat objects for you to evaluate on the console output

Comment: I stand corrected, after reading a bit more on Chrome's evaluation it looks like it's evaluated when you expand it the first time in the console.  Therefore you're unlikely to be able to force any deep evaluation.

Comment: @Sparksis the log it is not delayed, Chrome console keeps a reference to the object itself if it is passed by reference, all the mutables, or it just text out the inmutable. That's why you can inspect them after logging. For example, in newData = shuffle(originalData); newData and originalData variable will reference the same object, because they are just pointers after all. If you don't want originalData to change, then you should copy it recursively to a new array, then shuffle the new array.

Comment: @Matthew Herbst you log your original data, then you shuffle the it, the log reference will be pointing to the same array, but you inspected it after shuffled, so both are same. Try setting a breakpoint in the inspector right after the first log and before the shuffle, you'll see your original data in the log, step once and you'll see your shuffled data in the same first log

Comment: @JuanGarcia yeah, I see that, thank you. I took the code that adeneo posted in the JSFiddle in the comment above and that works perfectly using slice to create a new copy inside of shuffle. Thanks for the original answer!